# Android retrieving data from Firebase doesn't work for data models even it works for other data model in the project with similar codes

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am new in Android and working on an Android app which can retrieve data from firebase. There is a weird problem. I already successfully implemented the retrieving function for one data model of my program, and I used same codes just changed the variables but it doesn't work for another data model. I did many tests and I think the problem is in FirebaseHelper cuz there is no any data returned from the data snapshot. The error is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

The codes are shown below:

The Activity that shows the retrieved data in a listview.

```
public class TimeTableActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference db;
    FirebaseHelper firebasehelper;
    TimeTableAdapter adapter;
    ListView lv_CourseList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_table);

        //GET INTENT
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        String majorID = intent.getStringExtra("MAJOR_ID");

        lv_CourseList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_CourseList);

        //INITIALIZE FIREBASE DB
        db= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        firebasehelper=new FirebaseHelper(db);

        //ADAPTER
        adapter = new TimeTableAdapter(getApplicationContext(),firebasehelper.retrieveCourse(majorID, new CourseCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCourseCallback(ArrayList<CourseInfo> courseInfos) {

                        lv_CourseList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }));

        lv_CourseList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

FirebaseHelper:

```
public class FirebaseHelper{

    private DatabaseReference db;
    private ArrayList<Major> majors = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<CourseInfo> courseInfos = new ArrayList<>();

    public FirebaseHelper(DatabaseReference db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    //Save the Major info. into db
    public Boolean saveMajor(Major major)
    {
        Boolean saved = null;
        if(major==null)
        {
            saved =false;
        }else
        {
            try
            {
                db.child("Major").push().setValue(major);
                saved =true;

            }catch (DatabaseException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                saved =false;
            }
        }

        return saved;
    }

    //Save the Course info. into db
    public Boolean saveCourse(CourseInfo courseInfo)
    {
        Boolean saved = null;
        if(courseInfo==null)
        {
            saved =false;
        }else
        {
            try
            {
                db.child("CourseInfo").push().setValue(courseInfo);
                saved =true;

            }catch (DatabaseException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                saved =false;
            }
        }

        return saved;
    }


    public ArrayList<Major> retrieveMajor(final MajorCallbacks majorCallbacks){

        ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Major major = ds.getValue(Major.class);

                    if (major != null && major.getMajor_id() != null) {
                        majors.add(major);
                    }

                }

                majorCallbacks.onMajorCallback(majors);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Major major = ds.getValue(Major.class);

                    if (major != null && major.getMajor_id() != null) {
                        majors.add(major);
                    }
                }
                majorCallbacks.onMajorCallback(majors);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };

        db.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);

        if (!majors.isEmpty()){
            db.removeEventListener(childEventListener);
        }

        return majors;

    }



    public ArrayList<CourseInfo> retrieveCourse(String majorID, final CourseCallbacks courseCallbacks){

        ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    CourseInfo courseInfo = ds.getValue(CourseInfo.class);

                    if (courseInfo != null && courseInfo.getCourse_id() != null) {
                        courseInfos.add(courseInfo);
                    }

                }


                courseCallbacks.onCourseCallback(courseInfos);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    CourseInfo courseInfo = ds.getValue(CourseInfo.class);

                    if (courseInfo != null && courseInfo.getCourse_id() != null) {
                        courseInfos.add(courseInfo);
                    }

                }

                courseCallbacks.onCourseCallback(courseInfos);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
           db.child("CourseInfo").orderByChild("major_id").equalTo(majorID).addChildEventListener(childEventListener);



        return courseInfos;

    }


}
```

The `retrieveMajor` method works well even though it returns many null data and repetitive data, and I used the codes of `retrieveMajor` in `retrieveCourse`. It doesn't work, the `courseInfos` is always null. Even though I changed `db.child("CourseInfo").orderByChild("major_id").equalTo(majorID).addChildEventListener(childEventListener);`
to
`db.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);`
,still nothing is retrieved which means the problem is not the query (Probably the query is also wrong).

Adapter:

```
public class TimeTableAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<CourseInfo> courseInfos;

    public TimeTableAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CourseInfo> courseInfos) {
        this.context = context;
        this.courseInfos = courseInfos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return courseInfos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return courseInfos.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.model_timetable,viewGroup,false);
        }

        TextView tv_courseid= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_courseid);
        TextView tv_coursename= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_coursename);
        TextView tv_courseinstructor= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_courseinstructor);
        TextView tv_courseavailable= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_courseavailable);

        final CourseInfo courseInfo= (CourseInfo) this.getItem(position);

        tv_courseid.setText(courseInfo.getCourse_id());
        tv_coursename.setText(courseInfo.getCourse_name());
        tv_courseinstructor.setText(courseInfo.getCourse_instructor());
        tv_courseavailable.setText(courseInfo.getCourse_available());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Data model:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class CourseInfo {

    public String course_id;
    public String course_name;
    public int course_section;
    public String course_type;
    public double course_crdhrs;
    public String course_days;
    public String course_times;
    public String course_location;
    public int course_max;
    public int course_cur;
    public int course_available;
    public int course_wl;
    public double course_per;
    public String course_instructor;
    public String course_description;
    public String course_prerequire;
    public String major_id;

    public CourseInfo() {

    }

    public CourseInfo(String course_id, String course_name, int course_section, String course_type, double course_crdhrs, String course_days, String course_times, String course_location, int course_max, int course_cur, int course_available, int course_wl, double course_per, String course_instructor, String course_description, String course_prerequire, String major_id) {
        this.course_id = course_id;
        this.course_name = course_name;
        this.course_section = course_section;
        this.course_type = course_type;
        this.course_crdhrs = course_crdhrs;
        this.course_days = course_days;
        this.course_times = course_times;
        this.course_location = course_location;
        this.course_max = course_max;
        this.course_cur = course_cur;
        this.course_available = course_available;
        this.course_wl = course_wl;
        this.course_per = course_per;
        this.course_instructor = course_instructor;
        this.course_description = course_description;
        this.course_prerequire = course_prerequire;
        this.major_id = major_id;
    }

    public String getCourse_id() {
        return course_id;
    }

    public String getCourse_name() {
        return course_name;
    }

    public int getCourse_section() {
        return course_section;
    }

    public String getCourse_type() {
        return course_type;
    }

    public double getCourse_crdhrs() {
        return course_crdhrs;
    }

    public String getCourse_days() {
        return course_days;
    }

    public String getCourse_times() {
        return course_times;
    }

    public String getCourse_location() {
        return course_location;
    }

    public int getCourse_max() {
        return course_max;
    }

    public int getCourse_cur() {
        return course_cur;
    }

    public int getCourse_available() {
        return course_available;
    }

    public int getCourse_wl() {
        return course_wl;
    }

    public double getCourse_per() {
        return course_per;
    }

    public String getCourse_instructor() {
        return course_instructor;
    }

    public String getCourse_description() {
        return course_description;
    }

    public String getCourse_prerequire() {
        return course_prerequire;
    }

    public String getMajor_id() {
        return major_id;
    }

}
```

If you need more codes or information, please comment and let me know. I will really appreciate if you can also help me solve the null data and repetitive data problem cuz it makes the listview show many blank and repetitive items.

Comment: At which line is that error causing the problem?

Comment: The last line `lv_CourseList.setAdapter(adapter);` in TimeTableActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return something now that hasn't been loaded yet. With other words, you cannot just simply create a method that as a return type, an `ArrayList<Major>` and in the same time return that object. This is happening because those methods, `onChildAdded()`, `onChildChanged()` and so on, have an `asynchronous behaviour`, which means that are called even before you are getting/updating the data from/in the database. To solve this, you can move the declaration of that `ArrayList` inside one method and do what you need to do with it or dive into asynchronous world and use the last part of my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)**. You can take also a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.